# TSQL Syntax Error

Tags: t-sql

I'm wirting a tsql procedure to recreate all the views in one database onto a different dtabase.  I'm receiving the error "Incorrect syntax near +"  When I look  at the code though the syntax appears correct to me.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query?

```
USE [SOURCEDB]   
BEGIN  
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE CUR_V CURSOR FOR  
SELECT sc.text     
FROM sys.views av          
JOIN sys.syscomments sc ON sc.id = av.object_id  
OPEN CUR_V  
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_V INTO @SQL  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN    
EXEC sp_executesql N'USE [DESTINATIONDB] EXEC sp_executesql ' + @SQL + ''       
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_V INTO @SQL  END  CLOSE CUR_V  DEALLOCATE CUR_V  END
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to write all sentence in a single var: `set @sql = N'....` then use it as a `sp_executesql` parameter.

Comment: I tried that initially danihp but since its a view it doesnt work becuase the view statment has to be the first statement in the batch.  This is the reason for nesting the executesql statements.

Comment: Declare a new var @total_sql and set all command in this new var: `set @total_sql = N'Use ...' + @sql + ''` then execute `EXEC sp_executesql @total_sql`. Try this.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  Either Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean.  I think you're saying do something like the following.
declare &SQL NVARCHAR(max)
SET &SQL = 'use [SOURCEDB] CREATE VIEW xyz AS SELECT 1 AS x'
exec sp_executesql &sql
This would return the error "'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch."
changed @ to & due to comments issues

Comment: ok, try to full qualify database path instead to include `use` command: create view database.owner.view ....

Answer (score 1):

You can't do the + in the same line as `sp_executesql`

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
select @sql = N'USE [DESTINATIONDB] EXEC sp_executesql ' + @SQL + '' 
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

or possibly what you mean is

```
select @sql = N'USE [DESTINATIONDB] EXEC sp_executesql N''' + @SQL + ''''
```

Comment: Thanks podiluska.  I tried that suggestion but SQL Server is still saying the + is incorrect syntax.

Comment: Does the value in the table also contain a + ?

Comment: I dont believe so.  The values for the CREATE VIEWS are coming from the system tables (sys.views and sys.syscomments)  So anything contained in those is possible.  Most of the views are pretty simple thought (ie SELECT * FROM Table WHERE dtdeleted IS NULL)